# Google Vision API 'TypeError: invalid file'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-vision, vision-api

The following piece of code comes from Google's Vision API Documentation, the only modification I've made is adding the argument parser for the function at the bottom.

```
import argparse
import os
from google.cloud import vision
import io

def detect_text(path):
"""Detects text in the file."""
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.types.Image(content=content)

response = client.text_detection(image=image)
texts = response.text_annotations
print('Texts:')

for text in texts:
    print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))

    vertices = (['({},{})'.format(vertex.x, vertex.y)
                for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices])

    print('bounds: {}'.format(','.join(vertices)))

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", type=str,
    help="path to input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
detect_text(args)
```

If I run it from a terminal like below, I get this invalid file error:

```
PS C:\VisionTest> python visionTest.py --image C:\VisionTest\test.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "visionTest.py", line 31, in <module>
    detect_text(args)
  File "visionTest.py", line 10, in detect_text
    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
TypeError: invalid file: {'image': 'C:\\VisionTest\\test.png'}
```

I've tried with various images and image types as well as running the code from different locations with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like either the file doesn't exist or is corrupt since it isn't even read. Can you try another image and validate it is in the location you expect?